# jQuery POST Ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

i'm trying to post data from Server A, let's say: www.a.com to server B, www.b.com and then fetch the response from server B

I do it like this, this script runs on server A:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>    
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Naamloos document</title>
</head>

<body>

<form id="Form" onsubmit="validate();" method="post">
Email Address: <input type="text" id="email" name="email">
Password: <input type="text" id="password" name="password">
<input type="submit">
 </form>

<script>
function validate()
{
var e = $('email').value;
var p = $('password').value; //jQuery is easier to type
// the same as
// var p = document.getElementById('password').value;
var req = new Request({
    url: 'http://www.B.com/validate.php?',
    method: 'post',
    data: {'email' : e, 'password' : p},
    onComplete: function(response)
    {
        if (response == "Valid" ) 
        {
            alert("succes");
        }
        else
        {
            alert("blur");
        }
    }
}).send();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

But at this moment, after hitting the submit button, the only thing that happends is that the fields are being cleared, thats all.

Validate.php looks like this:

```
<?php echo "Valid"; ?>
```

Comment: is there any error printed in browser console ?

Comment: Add the  `onError` handler to your request. Log the response in the console using `console.log(response)`

Comment: And tell us what the `Request` class is, I don't know it

Comment: See http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ is likely a better place than anything from w3schools

Answer (score 2):

You're submitting the form, so the JavaScript never gets a chance to do anything significant. Since you haven't specified an `action`, it submits to the current URL and reloads the page.

1. Stop using intrinsic event attributes.
2. Use JS event binding (since you are using jQuery already, keep using it)
3. Capture the event object and prevent the default behaviour of the submit event

such:

```
<form id="Form" method="post">

$('#Form').on('submit', validate);

function validate (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var e = $('#email').val();
```

---

You also don't appear to have defined `Request` anywhere. You should probably switch to [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

---

Also note that Server B will have to give Server A permission to make Ajax requests to it using CORS.

Comment: Could you please correct your code? This isn't valid syntax... :)

Comment: Well, it was valid syntax, it just wouldn't work, but that bit was the OP's code :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this

```
var e = $('email').value;
var p = $('password').value;
```

with this

```
var e = $('#email').val();
var p = $('#password').val();
```